# std::unique example with no equivalence relationship (remove consecutive spaces)

Tags: c++, std

There is an example on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) on how to use `std::unique` to remove consecutive spaces from a string:

```
std::string s = "wanna go    to      space?";
auto end = std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char l, char r){
    return std::isspace(l) && std::isspace(r) && l == r;
});
// s now holds "wanna go to space?xxxxxxxx", where 'x' is indeterminate
std::cout << std::string(s.begin(), end) << '\n';
```

However, in the requirements section for unique it states

> Elements are compared using the given binary predicate p. The behavior
>   is undefined if it is not an equivalence relation.

So my question is: is the given example valid?
The predicate is clearly not reflexive (the two 'n' characters compare unequal) and thus not an equivalence relation.

Comment: It is an equivalence. All non-spaces are unique.

Comment: It is the reflexivity which is broken (`a ~ a`), symmetry is correct (`a ~ b <=> b ~ a`)

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, I just corrected this, I meant reflexive

Comment: With your edit, comment is wrong, the two `n` might be different, problem is that each letter (except space) is not equal to itself.

Comment: Ahh. In that case I think @Jarod42 is correct.

Comment: But isn't it for the function to define what is and what is not equal? Isn't the important thing that the function defines what is equal rater than (say) a *less than* relationship? I think it is simply saying the function will not work if you do not tell it which elements you consider equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate indeed doesn't respect [Equivalence_relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), in particular reflexivity:

```
a ~ a
```

The example you point may be valid though, first `'n'` can be different than second `'n'`.
problem is with self comparison which is false (except for space character).

One way to fix the predicate is to take address into account:

```
[](const char& l, const char& r)
{
    return (&l == &r)
        || (l == r && std::is_space(l));
}
```

The fact is that comparing with itself is mostly useless for that algorithm, so the UB here does what author expect in most implementation.

Valid implementation might check reflexivity of predicate, and if wrong does anything (as UB).

Comment: That's a neat trick.I would have assumed (without any particular reason) that the predicate is supposed to compare the iterator's `value_type` for equivalence, without relying on the objects' actual identity in memory. It's obvious that you can pass by reference, but not so obvious that you're allowed to use that information for the equivalence relationship.

Comment: Taking the address is not better! Copying a value is not supposed to change the result, e.g. ``const char n='n'; pred(n,n) /*== true*/; const char n2=n; pred(n,n2) /*== false*/;``

Comment: @ArneVogel: I would say it is more tricky, the predicate is correct (meet requirement of Equivalence for `const char&`), but is it compatible with given iterator ? *"The type of dereferenced ForwardIt must meet the requirements of [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable)."*. refence are not MoveAssignable, `char` is (but using other predicate).

Comment: @Jarod42: I doubt it. The standard (in [alg.unique]) refers to eliminating "equivalent elements". This implies that the predicate must be an equivalence relation *of elements* and not of references. Good catch regarding ``MoveAssignable``. Is ``char &`` ``MoveAssignable``? I don't know. I guess it would make more sense to require the iterator's ``value_type`` to satisfy this concept.

Answer (score 0):

unique: "Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range"

If you define an element for the sample predicate to be a space only, then all is correct. Equivalence should be applied only to spaces. 'n' is not a space so predicate returns false.